# How do I convert the Cookies collection to a generic list? Easily

Tags: .net, generics, .net-3.5

Anyone know how I can convert `Request.Cookies` into a `List<HttpCookie>`? The following didn't work as it throws an exception.

```
List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = new List<HttpCookie>(
    Request.Cookies.Cast<HttpCookie>());
```

Exception: *Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpCookie'*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the [`NameObjectCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.aspx) type that `Request.Cookies` derives from enumerates over the keys of the collection and not over the values. So when you enumerate over the `Request.Cookies` collection you are getting the keys:

```
public virtual IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new NameObjectKeysEnumerator(this);
}
```

This means that the following will work:

```
string[] keys = Request.Cookies.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

I guess you could try the following which might be considered ugly but will work:

```
List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = Request.Cookies.Keys.Cast<string>()
    .Select(x => Request.Cookies[x]).ToList();
```

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @Jon Benedicto in the comments section and in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922762/how-do-i-convert-the-cookies-collection-to-a-generic-list-easily/2922953#2922953) using the `AllKeys` property is more optimal as it saves a cast:

```
List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys
    .Select(x => Request.Cookies[x]).ToList();
```

Comment: But then you lose the key -> value connection :)

Comment: @Snake, I agree with you that this is not optimal from performance standpoint as it will enumerate the collection multiple times but if you have a couple of elements it might not be dramatical.

Comment: Using the AllKeys member of HttpCookieCollection saves a cast. See my answer for code.

Comment: This helped me solve an issue with XmlSerializer serializing the keys and not the values. My NameObjectCollectionBase subclass needed to override GetEnumerator as `return this.BaseGetValues().GetEnumerator();`

Comment: Note when 2 cookies with the same key is received (`a=1; a=2`) `Response.Cookies[string]` always return the first one (`a=1`). Instead you need to use something like `Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Select((_, x) => Request.Cookies[x])`

Answer (score 6):

If you really want a straight `List<HttpCookie>` with no key->value connection, then you can use Select in LINQ to do it:

```
var cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Select(x => Request.Cookies[x]).ToList();
```

Comment: IE can send multiple cookies with the same name if the cookies are created in separate domains. If this happens then the code above loses one of the cookies.

Comment: The code gets only the first cookie with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

The question may be a bit old, but the answers here are not covering all cases, because as pointed out by @C.M. there can be multiple cookies with the same name.

So the easiest way is to loop the cookies collection with a for loop:

```
var existingCookies = new List<HttpCookie>();

for (var i = 0; i < _httpContext.Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
{
    existingCookies.Add(_httpContext.Request.Cookies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.Cookies.Cast<HttpCookie>();` tries to cast the collection of keys to a collection of cookies. So it's normal that you get an error :)

It's a name -> value collection, so casting to a list wouldn't be good.

I would try converting it to a dictionary.

For example:

Since Cookies inherits from NameObjectCollectionBase you can [GetAllKeys()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.basegetallkeys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and use that list to get all the values and put them in a Dictionary.

For example:

```
Dictionary cookieCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach(var key in Request.Cookies.GetAllKeys())
{
    cookieCollection.Add(key, Request.Cookies.Item[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid iterating the keys by using the collection's `Count` with `Enumerable.Range`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Foo
{
  public static class WebHttpExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable<HttpCookie> AsEnumerable(this HttpCookieCollection webCookies) =>
      Enumerable
        .Range(0, webCookies.Count)
        .Select(ndx => webCookies[ndx]);

    public static IEnumerable<System.Net.Cookie> ToNetCookies(this HttpCookieCollection webCookies) => 
      webCookies
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new System.Net.Cookie(x.Name, x.Value));
  }
}
```