# How to convert HttpCookie DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a following code where I am trying to check `DateTime`

```
HttpCookie date1 = Request.Cookies.Get("Date1");

DateTime? aDate = date1 != null DateTime.ParseExact(date1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null): (DateTime?) null;
```

I also tried `Convert.ToDateTime(date1)` but none of them work. I got following exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error`

Comment: can you give us an example of `Date1`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922762/how-do-i-convert-the-cookies-collection-to-a-generic-list-easily  might be relevant. Can work your way to casting it to a string or something and turn that into the date object you want.

Comment: what was the value of `Date1` when that exception was generated. If it does not match the "dd/MM/yyyy" format, you may expect the error you got.

Comment: when I debug I see value in this format `03%2F31%2F2014`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments:

> when I debug I see value in this format 03%2F31%2F2014

Then try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(WebUtility.UrlDecode(date1.Value), "MM/dd/yyyy", null)
```

Note that `null` means to parse using the *current* culture.  If the value is *always* in that format, then you may wish to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead.

Or, if you are indeed mutating the value based on the current culture, then you should try this:

```
DateTime.Parse(WebUtility.UrlDecode(date1.Value))
```

I'm not sure why your value is URL Encoded.  Perhaps you should also investigate how you *set* the cookie to begin with.   You should *probably* be setting using the ISO8601 format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) with the invariant culture.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [**Decode**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your values. Then you will see that it is `03/31/2014`, which is different to what you have provided in your format. Use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(date1.Value),
                "MM/dd/yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Make sure to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`, this could cause a problem on machines where the default culthre has a different  data separator than `/`

[`WebUtility.UrlDecode Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is only provided with .Net framework 4.5. Use [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are targeting .Net framework 4.0 or lower.

Comment: Now I got this error `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.`

Comment: @Lakhae - Then that's not the string being passed in.